# Hypergenesis and Triggered abilities

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If an opponent casts (or cascades into) [Hypergenesis](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Hypergenesis), starting with the caster each player takes it in turns to put a Creature, Artifact, Land or Enchantment onto the Battlefield. This can be repeated any number of times, and as a result potentially lead to some confusion.

**1)** I put an [Emrakul, the Aeons Torn](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Emrakul%2C%20the%20Aeons%20Torn) onto the battlefield, my opponent puts an [Oblivion Ring](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Oblivion%20Ring) onto the battlefield. Next, I put a [Griselbrand](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Griselbrand) onto the Battlefield, my opponent puts a [Detention Sphere](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Detention%20Sphere) onto the battlefield. Finally, I put an [Iona, Shield of Emeria](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Iona%2C%20Shield%20of%20Emeria) onto the battlefield, My opponent puts an Island onto the battlefield. **Can my opponent exile my Iona?**

**2)** I put a [Goblin Matron](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Goblin%20Matron) onto the battlefield, **can I fetch a [Goblin Ringleader](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Goblin%20Ringleader) and put that onto the battlefield in the next round of Hypergenesis?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When an ability triggers, all the game does is make a note of it. The triggered ability is only placed on the stack the next time a player would get priority. This is only after [Hypergenesis](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Hypergenesis) has finished resolving.

> 603.2. Whenever a game event or game state matches a triggered ability’s trigger event, that ability automatically triggers. The ability doesn’t do anything at this point.

> 603.3. Once an ability has triggered, its controller puts it on the stack as an object that’s not a card the next time a player would receive priority. [...]

So 1) yes, and 2) no.

Answer (score 3):

1. yes.
2. no.

From the Rulings sections on gatherer:[Hypergenesis](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=113533)

> Anything that triggers during the resolution of this will wait to be
>   put on the stack until everything is put onto the battlefield and
>   resolution is complete. The player whose turn it is will put all of
>   his or her triggered abilities on the stack in any order, then each
>   other player in turn order will do the same. (The last ability put on
>   the stack will be the first one that resolves.)